# PHP dynamic dropdown not saving selection

Tags: php, list, drop-down-menu, save

Very new to PHP scripting. I've been able to use this code on one page to select and save the selection

```
 <?php

    $select_query=   "Select IP from Insolvency_Practitioners";
    $select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);
    echo "<select IP='IP'>";
    while ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
    {
        echo "<option value='' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["IP"])."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

 ?>
```

and it works fine.

However I have transfered the code to another page to do a similar operation and it fails to save. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need be sure your mysql connection is oppened in this page too. Is it?

Comment: What is the error message? don't use mysql_fetch_array but mysqli_fetch_array instead.